# Convert multidimensional array with differing keys to csv with headers

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array of data that is presented as follows:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CallID] => 793415338
        [StartTime] => 2016-10-04 17:21:53
        [CallingNo] => +15555555555
        [queue1_time] => 94
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [CallID] => 1718936847
        [StartTime] => 2016-10-04 17:29:41
        [CallingNo] => +15555555556
        [queue1_time] => 64
        [queue2_time] => 96
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [CallID] => 497342634
        [StartTime] => 2016-10-04 17:34:57
        [CallingNo] => +15555555557
        [queue4_time] => 47
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [CallID] => 1298245252
        [StartTime] => 2016-10-04 17:35:33
        [CallingNo] => +15555555558
        [queue1_time] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [CallID] => 1214106933
        [StartTime] => 2016-10-04 17:35:38
        [CallingNo] => +15555555559
        [queue1_time] => 53
        [queue2_time] => 31
    )
....
)
```

I would like to parse all of the data in this array and convert it to a csv with a header above each set of array values that have matching complete key sets. Output would look like the following:

```
CallID,StartTime,CallingNo,queue1_time
793415338,2016-10-04 17:21:53,+15555555555,94
1298245252,2016-10-04 17:35:33,+15555555558,5

CallID,StartTime,CallingNo,queue1_time,queue2_time
1718936847,2016-10-04 17:29:41,+15555555556,64,96
1214106933,2016-10-04 17:35:38,+15555555559,53,31

CallID,StartTime,CallingNo,queue4_time
497342634,2016-10-04 17:34:57,+15555555557,47
```

Any further tips or tricks to shorten this code would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're going to have to loop over all the entries to get the list of available keys. Then loop over again adding the keys' values to their respective keys in the csv.

Comment: Doing what you ask is quite easy, but are you really sure thats what you want, as the CSV file you want to create will be next to useless as you have specified it

Comment: The data points sorted in the output above will not be used in the same traditional sense as a csv file. This is more or less a request to sort the data for all matching key sets into a flat text file and place the key names above each set of data that falls under those matching keys.

Comment: Did you try to write some code yourself or you are looking for someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: So how were you thinking of sorting the arrays so they all get created in nice blocks were all the rows with similiar parameters get written together.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this functional with the following code but I am guessing there is a simpler more efficient method to perform this task:

```
$key_array = array();
foreach (array_keys($overflow_array) as $paramName){
  foreach ($overflow_array[$paramName] as $key => $value){
    $key_array[$paramName][] = $key;
  }
}
$key_array = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $key_array)));

function array_keys_exist($keys, $array){
  if (count($keys) != count($array)){
    return false;
  }
  foreach($keys as $num => $key){
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $array))return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$output = fopen('php://temp/maxmemory:1048576', 'w');
if($output === FALSE) {
  die('Failed to open temporary file');
}

foreach ($key_array as $keyset => $value){
  $keys = array_values($value);
  fputcsv($output, $keys);
  foreach ($overflow_array as $oflow => $oflow_key){
    if (array_keys_exist($keys, $overflow_array[$oflow]) == true){
      fputcsv($output, $overflow_array[$oflow]);
    }
  }
}
rewind($output);
$csv = stream_get_contents($output);
fclose($output);

print_r($csv);
```